# Why my script end before outpitong results PHP

Tags: php

My script restarts and does not make output. Here is the code:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit3']) || isset($_POST['submit2'])) : ?>

<?php else : ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <br>Nacin rada 1
        <br>Nacin rada 2
        <input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Nacin rada 1">
        <input type="submit" name="submit3" value="Nacin rada 2">
    </form>

<?php endif ?>

<?php if (isset($_POST['submit2'])) : ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        Zeljena dubina: <input size="5" type="text" name="dubina"><br>
        Ulazni kut glave: <input size="5" type="text" name="uk"><br>
        Maximalan kut pomaka glave: <input value="2" size="5" type="text" name="kpg"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Unesi Vrijednosti">
    </form>

    <?php 
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //preuzimanje formova
            $_POST['submit2'] = true;
            $kpg = 0;
            $dubina = (int)$_POST['dubina'];


 //some math stuff and working output

        }
    ?>

<?php elseif (isset($_POST['submit3'])) : ?>

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        Zeljena dubina: <input size="5" type="text" name="dubina"><br>
        Zeljena udaljenost: <input size="5" type="text" name="duljina"><br>
        Maximalan kut pomaka glave: <input value="2" size="5" type="text"  name="kpg"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit5" value="Unesi Vrijednosti">
    </form>

    <?php
        if (isset($_POST['submit5'])) { //preuzimanje formova
            $_POST['submit3'] = true;
            $kpg = 0;
            $dubina = (int)$_POST['dubina'];
            $duljina = (int)$_POST['duljina'];


        // some math stuff and working output
        }
    ?>


<?php endif ?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit4" value="Kreni ponovno">
</form>
```

So basically what i want to do is first to show 2 buttons, then after clicking on one of buttons to go in that mode, in that mode we have to enter some parameters, after the we click another button to enter data. Then script should do code and output final results...When i didnt want this solution with 2 modes all worked nicely, tried to turn all errors and info but nothing. I think the problem is in if statements connected w buttons but cant find it

Comment: It would probably help if you tidied up your wall of code. :)

Comment: Enable error reporting and see what errors you have.

Comment: ok, i tidied my code :) deleted working (what i think is irrelevant) part for this problem

Answer (score 3):

You're using the if shorthand notation incorrectly.
It needs to be in this order: `$result = ($value == 'content' ? true : false);`

If you want to use the notation with `endif`, drop the questionmark.

```
if($a > $b):
    echo $a." is greater than ".$b;
elseif($a == $b): // Note the combination of the words.
    echo $a." equals ".$b;
else:
    echo $a." is neither greater than or equal to ".$b;
endif;
```

In case you haven't yet, I would suggest changing your PHP log level to show warnings and info messages. It will provide you with some more information as to where things are going wrong.

Comment: "php doesn't work with `endif`" what? Yes it does.